# Getting a future unix timestamp using a specific date and time?

Tags: php, datetime, unix-timestamp

I run a business and have been developing a CMS / invoicing on my website.

"Appointment"
12:30 PM Thu Aug 5 2021

Though I can format this any way I like,  is it possible at all to get the unix time stamp of that?

The purpose of doing so would be so I can just insert the unix timestamp and be able to sort my appointments by the closest to date.

Thank you.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to convert a date format to unix. Is that right? If so: `$timestamp = strtotime('1/1/2021 21:00');` (where 1/1/2021 you will use your date and time)

Comment: oh wow yes that's exactly what I need!  thank you

Comment: Just added my comment as answer so others can find it easier!

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('1/1/2021 21:00');
```

Replace `1/1/2021 21:00` to the desired date.