# Getting a Unix Timestamp for a future date and time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I get a future unix timestamp in Javacript? ie, pass "2023-03-08 13:05:00" and get a unix timestamp corresponding to that time.

All the examples I see use the getTime() function which is the current time like this:
[Javascript: future time as UNIX timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213427/javascript-future-time-as-unix-timestamp)

I found a solution in Php which I think serves the purpose I am looking for:
[Getting a future unix timestamp using a specific date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68606574/getting-a-future-unix-timestamp-using-a-specific-date-and-time)

Is there a similar function in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create a Date object for the future time

var futureTime = new Date("2023-03-08 13:05:00");

// Get the Unix timestamp (in milliseconds) for the future time

var futureTimestamp = futureTime.getTime();

// Convert milliseconds to seconds

var futureUnixTimestamp = Math.floor(futureTimestamp / 1000);

console.log(futureUnixTimestamp); // Output: 1678385100
```

Comment: Doesn't the answer given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213427/javascript-future-time-as-unix-timestamp suffice?